# Why is my onEnter prop not being triggered? (react-native-router-flux v4)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux

I have created my own Scene component with a condition onEnter property. It checks the redux store, if you have certain information, and is supposed to lead you to right scene. However, it does not seem to run nor even return a console log, once I trigger navigation to that particular scene.

I have tried console logging something like "Hey I got hit!." My console remains unchanged upon entering the Scene.

````
const Auth = props => {
    const { component, key, userLoggedIn, hasUserInfo, hasSellerAccount} = props

    const isLoggedIn = (userLoggedIn, hasUserInfo, hasSellerAccount) => {
        if(userLoggedIn && hasUserInfo && hasSellerAccount){
            Actions.admin()
        } else if (userLoggedIn && !hasUserInfo){
            Actions.userInformation()
        } else if (userLoggedIn && hasUserInfo && !hasSellerAccount){
            Actions.createAccount()
        } else if (!userLoggedIn){
            Actions.logIn()
        }
    }
    return(
        <Scene
        key={key}
        onEnter={isLoggedIn(userLoggedIn, hasUserInfo, hasSellerAccount)}
        component={component}
        {...props}
        />
    )
} ```

I expected it to check the conditions and redirect you to the correct page.
````

Comment: try modifying it to `onEnter={() => isLoggedIn(userLoggedIn, hasUserInfo, hasSellerAccount)}`. I am not sure isLoggedIn would be called like the way you've done it. Instead try calling the function inside an arrow function.